# What is the difference between TaskMethodAsync(); and _ = TaskMethodAsync();?

Tags: c#

In fact....i just want to hide compiler's warning!

code :

```
TaskMethodAsync()

_=TaskMethodAsync()
```

Comment: They'll do the same thing, yeah, except the second case does not display a warning. If that's what you're looking for, go for it.

Comment: Both options are incorrect since you are not awaiting in either case.

Comment: The second one explicitly acknowledges that something is returned, but that it's not needed so it's discarded. Which is the code way of saying: "I know what I'm doing. I don't need the return value."

Comment: @TanveerBadar erm. You don't always have to await an async. If you did then the await keyword wouldn't be needed/the compiler could put the await in for you

Comment: @Kurris do you understand the significance associated with the fact that this method is ...Async?

Comment: @TanveerBadar I'm curious why they are incorrect since I have used the second option in the past to "fire-and-forget" async methods from synchronous methods.

Comment: They are only correct for fire and forget scenarios, otherwise bugs waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference!

You get the warning for the first option, because when you have a function that returns a value, and you don't assign or otherwise use that value at all, that's a strong indication you don't understand the function and maybe have a bug.

The second option does not produce a warning because you were explicit about saying, "Yes, I am aware this method returns a value, but I really do mean to just throw it away."

Comment: Might be worth enhancing the answer to make it more specifically about awaitables- we all call non awaitables and ignore the return value all the time without any kind of warning.. I think the OP is looking to specifically resolve the "because this call is not awaited.." warning